# How do I add Google Analytics cross domain tracking in Squarespace?

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager, squarespace

I have setup my site using Squarespace. I am also using Google Analytics to track site activity including eCommerce. When I go form product cart page to checkout page on my site it take we to following url secure.squarespace.com/commerce/checkout but during this process my old session is lost. In order to keep track of my existing client that is going from cart to checkout google analytics allow setting cross domain tracking between two distinct domain.

How can I set cross domain tracking in Squarespace? or Is there any way that my session activity is not lost and similar user is track between main site and Squarespace checkout pages. ?

Squarespace allow Google Analytics ecommerce tracking by embedded code, you just need to enter the google analytics id to start tracking, the embedded code belongs to classic google analytics and there is no way you can edit it (at least not in my knowledge) in order to modify allow linker command within code to enable cross domain tracking. I can use my own Google Analytics code or Google Tag Manager if preferred through code injection but for that I will have to remove the build in google analytics code (classic analytics) which will result in loss of ecommerce data.

I need to know if there is anyway to enable cross domain tracking within the embedded google analytics code or maybe use code injection and use my own Google Analytics code (remove the embedded) and still get ecommerce data for Google Analytics.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question explaining what you've tried already. Have you you seen the analytics.js developer guide on [cross-domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain) yet? The more details you give the higher quality your answers will be.

Comment: I have tried way to modify embedded google analytics code(classic code) in order to enable cross domain tracking. Also I have tried to lookup for ways to get ecommerce data within Google Analytics without embedded code(input modified ga code through code injection) but failed to do both. Any help will be highly appreciated.